# how to parse reverse Polish Notation JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an input:

```
{"expressions":["16 10 / 5 * 20 +","10 11 0 + 1 * + 0 9 - -","13 0 * 11 - 8 -","0 6 + 13 17 * -","15 19 14 1 - + * 1 1 / /"],"id":"1c5322060eed42ca932acfc263063b10"}
```

I want to get the array  `[["16","10","/","5","*","20","+"],["10","11","0",…]…]`

Comment: split on white space if you can count on the formatting always being white space delimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse JSON and split result by spaces:

```js
const input = '{"expressions":["16 10 / 5 * 20 +","10 11 0 + 1 * + 0 9 - -","13 0 * 11 - 8 -","0 6 + 13 17 * -","15 19 14 1 - + * 1 1 / /"],"id":"1c5322060eed42ca932acfc263063b10"}'

const expressions = JSON.parse(input).expressions

console.log(expressions.map(
  expression => expression.split(' ')
))
```